# Split string into two integers, python

Tags: python

I have problem and trying to get next:

new_string = "35"     #and this result must be like new_int = 3+5.

How im available to do this? I know the type conversion, but not a clue how i should do this.

Comment: `sum(map(int, '35'))`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are new to the python, i suggest you doing it using

```
int(new_string[0]) # 3

int(new_string[1]) # 5
```

So now you have 2 integers, you can to whatever you want